# Cognos Reports - No Prompt Page

Tags: prompt, cognos-8

I am new to Cognos reports, so bear with me.

I have a report that has two parameters (call them x and y).  I have a prompt page for x and y.  The user can supply those values and click finish to be taken to the report.  I am looking for a way to only show that prompt page if those parameters are not passed in the url string.  If those parameters are set, I want to go directly to the report.  I have tried some js to automatically act as though the finish button has been called, but I am just getting cognos errors.  Any suggestions as to how I can accomplish this?  The prompt page is having the prompt controls set to the values for x and y in the url.

js -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
promptAction('finish');
</script>
```

cognos error -

> The secondary request failed.  The requested session does not exist
>   and the secondary request does not contain enough information to
>   recreate the session.  Contact your Administrator.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am looking for a way to only show that prompt page if those parameters are not passed in the url string"? Is the report being called from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to append *&run.prompt=false* to your URL string to skip the prompt page. This only works if you supply all the prompts - it will error if even one is missing.